# Automatically creating div's using data from a sql table

Tags: php, sql, html

I'm trying to create duplicate `div`s with different data in each obtained from a SQL database. I have the code creating the `div`s and populating the correct fields with the correct data, but my code is nesting the `div`s within each other.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, location, amountRequested FROM     fundable");

while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<div class='widgetLoan'>";
echo "<div class='title'><h6>".$temp['name']."</h6><span class='widgetLoanCat'>Category</span>";
echo "<div class='num'><a href='#' class='blueNum'>".$temp['amountRequested']."</a></div>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not closing the "title" div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, location, amountRequested FROM     fundable");

while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<div class='widgetLoan'>";
echo "<div class='title'><h6>".$temp['name']."</h6><span class='widgetLoanCat'>Category</span></div>";
echo "<div class='num'><a href='#' class='blueNum'>".$temp['amountRequested']."</a></div>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I have been Staring at this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to close a `</div>` tag

change

```
echo "<div class='title'><h6>".$temp['name']."</h6><span class='widgetLoanCat'>Category</span>";
```

for

```
echo "<div class='title'><h6>".$temp['name']."</h6><span class='widgetLoanCat'>Category</span></div>";
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I have been Staring at this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a `</div>` tag to me.