# How to auto create divs depending on the data in mysql table using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, e-commerce

I want to create an ecommerce website, using PHP and mySQL DB. I have this code below and I want (with the use of php if possible), after connecting to sql DB(I did this) to repeat this DIV depending on the entries in the DB table and echo the data of each entry in table. I found this but I don't know if it's the right example: [Automatically creating div's using data from a sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124669/automatically-creating-divs-using-data-from-a-sql-table)

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 agileinfo_new_products_grid agileinfo_new_products_grid_mobiles">
<div class="agile_ecommerce_tab_left mobiles_grid">
    <div class="hs-wrapper hs-wrapper2">
        <img src="images/<image>.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div class="hs_bottom hs_bottom_sub1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5><a href="#"><Itemname></a></h5> 
    <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
        <p><i class="item_price"><Price></i></p>
        <p><i class="item_price"><Description></i></p>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="Itemname" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="Price"/>   
            <button type="submit" class="cart">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, its the correct way. from the link

Comment: You've found a good example, why not implement it?

Comment: it's something like asp <repeater> right??

Comment: That link is a good starting point, just loop through your database results and replace your fields with whatever you've called them in your database each time you loop, like they have in the link you've provided does.

Comment: cause i found a few hundred other examples and none of them worked, so i'd like to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided above will work just fine, all you need to do is put the div/div's you want to generate multiple times inside a loop. then they will be generated as long as the loop condition is met.

> But though the example u provided works but you need to note that it
>   is using `mysql_*` functions which are depreciated and no longer
>   supported by newer php versions .

Therefore I would advice that you learn about prepared statements instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

consider the following :

```
<?php

    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM products")->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($sql as $row):?>
<div class="col-md-4 agileinfo_new_products_grid agileinfo_new_products_grid_mobiles">
<div class="agile_ecommerce_tab_left mobiles_grid">
    <div class="hs-wrapper hs-wrapper2">
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row['productImg'];?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div class="hs_bottom hs_bottom_sub1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['item_name'];?></a></h5> 
    <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
        <p><i class="item_price"> Price : <?php echo $row['item_price'];?></i></p>
        <p><i class="item_price">Description <?php echo $row['item_description'];?></i></p>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $row['item_name'];?>" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['item_price'];?>"/>   
            <button type="submit" class="cart">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>

<?php

    endforeach;
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php

    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    while ($row = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):?>
<div class="col-md-4 agileinfo_new_products_grid agileinfo_new_products_grid_mobiles">
<div class="agile_ecommerce_tab_left mobiles_grid">
    <div class="hs-wrapper hs-wrapper2">
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row['productImg'];?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div class="hs_bottom hs_bottom_sub1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['item_name'];?></a></h5> 
    <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
        <p><i class="item_price"> Price : <?php echo $row['item_price'];?></i></p>
        <p><i class="item_price">Description <?php echo $row['item_description'];?></i></p>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $row['item_name'];?>" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['item_price'];?>"/>   
            <button type="submit" class="cart">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>

<?php

    endwhile;
?>
```

Where `$pdo` is your database connection string.

This will fetch data and generates the div for each product.

If you not using prepared statements for your application, I would advice you to use them more especially pdo prepared statements, below are the places you can learn pdo prepared statements

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach

http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: I should learn about PDO. What i get after making the changes is this "Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchall()".

Comment: You need pdo connection, u no longer using mysqli. on the links I gave above there's a way to connect.... comment here wit ur code so I can see it or add in your question

Comment: you want me to send the php string for connecting to db??

Comment: Yes I want that

Comment: <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "products";

// Conn
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

// Check conn
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>

Comment: hence you getting that error, you made mysqli connection but using pdo functions your connection need to b pdo

Comment: this is what u must have : `<?php
 

 $host = '127.0.0.1';
 $db   = 'products';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 $charset = 'utf8';

 $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
 $opt = [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
   ];


$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

?>`

Comment: Ok got that! I will check the links you sent me and i will correct it! Thank you again! :)

Comment: Why does it say undefined index? I'm useless!! xD :P

Comment: what index is undifined?

Comment: All those i'm trying to get from sql table. Itemname, description, price and image.

Comment: does your table have those rows?

Comment: Yes. As i see in the links after <?php $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM items");while ($row = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):, should i close the php right away or at the end of the div. I hope you understand what i mean

Comment: I did. And it keeps showing "Undefined index" form itemname, price, description. And i write this to each section <?php echo $row['image'];?>

Comment: do u have itemname on your table?

Comment: Is there any way to send you a pic of my table?? xD 
In my sql table i have the id, itemname, descr, image and price! and it keeps telling me undefined index. Is there any chance i made something wrong with my code? Cause i think thats the problem

Comment: join me here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138308/discussion-between-masivuye-cokile-and-bob

Comment: low rep to talk to chat. want me to tell you my email??