# How to create multiple dynamic divs that change based on different database data with php / pdo / css

Tags: php, html, css, pdo

I'm new to programming so this could be something basic/obvious but I'm trying to design a basic grid style page using small div rectangles to display each staff member in a new row and then any jobs that are assigned to that staff member will display inline with the first div that shows their name.

- I have a staff database and a jobs database
- The jobs database has an assigned_to column, if a job is assigned to someone their name or id will be here

The logic I'm trying to implement here:

- If there is a staff member in the staff db, then create a div for them (or "a row on the main page") - **WORKING**
- Then if their name appears in 'assigned_to' on any particular job then also show that particular job beside the first div. - **WORKING only for the first staff member**
- Continue until there are no more jobs that have any staff members name in the 'assigned_to' column

**The issue is I can only get it to show the assigned jobs to the very first staff member, its like the loop I'm using to display jobs just stops after the first staff member and doesn't continue to find other jobs that are also assigned to other staff members.**

It will happily display 5 different jobs that have been assigned to the first staff member but it doesn't continue to check if anything has been assigned to the other staff members after that.

And it will happily display a 'Test Job' I write in manually for each staff member that isn't dynamically generated from database data.

There are 2 similar questions that I have found
[How to auto create divs depending on the data in mysql table using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855338/how-to-auto-create-divs-depending-on-the-data-in-mysql-table-using-php)
[Automatically creating div's using data from a sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124669/automatically-creating-divs-using-data-from-a-sql-table) but they don't really cover displaying certain divs only based on names matching in a database.

This is my code so far thats almost working

- I just copy and pasted the database select query (since it worked for the staff members) and gave it a different variable (is this correct practice? or is there a way to select what I need from 2 databases in just one query?)

```
    $sql = 'SELECT staff_id, name, role
            FROM tbl_staff
            ORDER BY staff_id';
    $q = $pdo->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $sql2 = 'SELECT job_addy, job_type, assigned_to
            FROM tbl_jobs';
    $q2 = $pdo->query($sql2);
    $q2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

- Then I've got one main while loop which creates a rectangle and a row for each staff member seems to work nicely.
- After the first staff div is created I have tried to use the same while loop to get the job data and place another div beside that one (only if its assigned to them).
- The third div that says 'Test Job' is just one I added to test the layout, it appears for each staff member and seems to prove the layout works, **it leads me to believe my problem lies within the second while loop and the if statement that follows it.**

```
        <div class ="main">
            <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
                <div class ="staffsq">
                    <span><strong><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']); ?></strong></br>
                    (<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['role']); ?>)</span>
                </div>
                
                <?php while ($row2 = $q2->fetch()): ?>
                    <?php if ($row['name'] == $row2['assigned_to']): ?>
                        <div class ="jobsq">
                            <span><strong><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row2['job_addy']); ?></strong></br>
                            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row2['job_type']); ?></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                
                <div class ="jobsq">
                    <span><strong>Test Job</strong></br>
                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']); ?></span>
                </div>
                </br>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

And the css is just giving the size of the rectangles and helping position them inline.

Everything is pretty basic, I would just like to get the main function of assigning jobs working.

```
.main {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}


.staffsq {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #99ccff; 
    height: 92.7px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

.jobsq {
    position: relative;
    left: 155px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffff99; 
    height: 92.7px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
}
```